# Missing level for cache map service

Tags: arcgis-server

I am having this issue where caching is missing one of the levels (level 13). I am trying to find out how to resolve this issue.

L9  -  1,155,581 - OK
L10 - 577,790 - OK
L11 - 288895 - OK
L12 - 144447, OK
L13 - 72223, MISSING, don’t show at all for some areas
L14 - 36111, OK 
L15 - 18055, OK
L16 - 9027, OK
L17 - OK
L18 - OK

Thanks
Jay

Comment: Which version and SP are you running? v10 has some known issues here that there are workarounds for.

Comment: I am using Server 10 but our server install doesnt have any service pack, I am going to upgrade to SP2 and see if this makes a difference.

Comment: Sp2 does have some fixes in it to address issue. Are you building a really large cache (mine is a whole state)? ESRI found that only way to solve the issue was to use a fishnet and chop it up to easier slices. 9.3.1 didn't have this issue but I could make it fail all the time; and like you I would find large chunks of several of the smaller scales missing.

Comment: I'm having an issue where the tiles are created but are not being pulled for some reason, so all I get is a blank map when checking the REST endpoint, I see no request

Comment: @user2469, Please provide answers for the answer section.  You could use the add comment option instead.